# Vue.js vuelidate: How to debounce async custom validator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, vuelidate

I have a validator that checks if username is already registered in database. It worked fine, except for the fact, that the request was send to the server with each character entered - which is way to often. So i tried to debounce the setting of the username variable value but all i'm getting is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
at a.NHnr.q.methods.debounceUsername.H.a.debounce.leading
```

Vue script:

```
import uniqueUsername from '../validation/uniqueUsername'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
    name: "signUpPage",
    data() {
      return {
        credentials: {
          username: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      debounceUsername:
        _.debounce(function (e) {
          this.credentials.username = e.target.value;
        }, 200, {leading: false, trailing: true})
    },
    validations: {
      credentials: {
        username: {
          uniqueUsername: uniqueUsername
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Html:

```
    <b-field :label="msg('usernameLabel')"
             :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.credentials.username.$error }">
      <b-input size="is-large" type="text" class="form__input"
               icon="account" name="username" v-on:input="debounceUsername" autofocus="">
      </b-input>
    </b-field> 
//b-field and b-input are from buefy library
```

Custom validator (uniqueUsername.js):

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default value => {
  if (value.trim().length === 0) return true;
  let usernameUnique;
  return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
    await axios('/isUsernameUnique', {
      method: "post",
      data: value,
      headers: {'Content-type': 'text/plain'}
    }).then((response) => usernameUnique = response.data);
    if (usernameUnique) resolve('username is unique');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
I had to change

```
this.credentials.username = e.target.value;
```

to:

```
this.credentials.username = e;
```

and it works now - frequency of sending requests is now max one every 200ms

Answer (score 6):

> One solution is to check when the user focused out of input field (blur) and then to run the async validations.So:

```
<input @blur="$v.username.$touch" v-model.lazy="username" />
```

> The script:

```
export default {
  data () {
   return {
    username: ''
   }
  },
  validations: {
    username: {
     required,
     isUnique(username) {
       if (username === '') return true
       return axios.get('/checkUsername')
                 .then(res => {
                   return res.data //res.data has to return true or false after checking if the username exists in DB
                 }) 
     }
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: in order to work this code you have to import axios and required from vuelidate
>
> Also keep in mind.The backend has to return false if the username is unique in order the above code to work correctly

Comment: That's poor UX if you want to provide live updates, though — the user now has to tab out of the field to see if the username's taken, then tab back in to change it.

Comment: Despite that we have required on username, should we check for `username === ''`?